# Repeating Running Numbers along side MySQL Results

Tags: mysql, sql

This seems like something that should be fairly common, so this could be as simple as giving me the right vocabulary for what I'm describing.

I want to return the results of a query and in a column I want to return a repeating number sequence of 1, 2, 3.

Desired Result Set:

```
Num    Result
---------------
1      result1
2      result2
3      result3
1      result4
2      result5
```

Now I can return a basic list of three numbers using the basic :

```
SELECT @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS ROW FROM 'use any table with data in it' t join (SELECT @ROW := 0) t2 LIMIT 3
```

I just can't find a way of blending this with my query to return the result I want. The best I've come up with returns a repeating 1,2,3 but repeats each item in the query for each number (as you'd expect).

```
Num    Result
---------------
1      result1
2      result1
3      result1
1      result2
2      result2
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE Results (Result varchar(10));
INSERT INTO Results (`Result`) VALUES ('result1');
INSERT INTO Results (`Result`) VALUES ('result2');
INSERT INTO Results (`Result`) VALUES ('result3');
INSERT INTO Results (`Result`) VALUES ('result4');
INSERT INTO Results (`Result`) VALUES ('result5');

CREATE TABLE Randoms (Random varchar(10));
INSERT INTO Randoms (`Random`) VALUES ('whatever1');
INSERT INTO Randoms (`Random`) VALUES ('whatever2');
INSERT INTO Randoms (`Random`) VALUES ('whatever3');

--Initial Query
SELECT Result 

  FROM Results

  ORDER BY Result ASC;


--Closest I've come (not close enough)
SELECT b.Num,
       a.Result 

  FROM Results a,
       (SELECT @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS Num FROM Randoms t join (SELECT @ROW := 0) t2 LIMIT 3) b

  ORDER BY a.Result ASC;
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I've learned over the past 45 minutes that I have a single minded hatred of SQLfiddle. As an alternative I have included the SQL required to recreate the failed scenario that I am hoping to rectify. Hopefully this is enough to get a handle on the problem. I hope that my original desired result set is enough.

Comment: What's the randoms bit for?

Comment: You can't use the table you are pulling the query from (reason unknown just throws an error most likely to do with the order that variables are set) And you can't use DUAL as you need a table with rows in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this...

```
SELECT MOD(i,3)+1
     , result 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT @i:=@i+1 i
            , result 
         FROM results
            , ( SELECT @i:=2 ) vals 
        ORDER 
           BY result
     ) x;
```

Comment: I just saw the IF() solution below which in my head is definitely simpler, however your answer was the first that worked and is now built into my platform. Thanks for your patients.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do this with `mod()`, I think an `if()` is simpler:

```
SELECT @row := if(@row < 3, @row + 1, 1) as Num,
       a.Result 
FROM Results a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @row := 0) vars
ORDER BY a.Result ASC;
```

I'm not sure what the table `randoms` is for.  It doesn't seem necessary to the problem.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2feeed/7) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: While your answer is the first one I didn't have to sit down with paper to understand (MOD was never my strong point) I already accepted an answer above. Hopefully the up vote goes a bit towards helping. The randoms was so that you could have rownums for the number generator to work, but essentially I was barking up the wrong tree with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use MOD function like this:

```
SET @ROW = 0;
SELECT 
  @ROW := @ROW +1 as RowNum,  
  (@ROW + 2) % 3 + 1 as Result 
FROM MyTable
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa299/7

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using this SQL. It won't work stand alone without defining ROW and I can't seem to find a way to blend it into what I'm currently using to make it work. If I throw in a table and then join that with (SELECT @ROW := 0) I just get the number 3 repeated.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Although it probably stems from my very limited ability to grasp math. It just kept repeating the number 3 for me.